# Why some values are inserting when i update setting in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I'm new in opencart. Can any one let me know Why some key values are inserting when i update setting in opencart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are editing you settings in OpenCart administration and hit *Save* button, actually what happens is that **all of your current** settings are deleted and then **inserted again**.

Therefore if you are relying on some setting's ID, it is incorrect assumption and you should be relying on the setting's keys instead.

Even if you are modifying only certain group of settings (e.g. payment options), even those are deleted by their *group key* and inserted again.